# useRef causing re-render, Is this the expected behavior?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Mere declaration of useRef causes my component to re-render. Is this the behavior one would expect? if yes, a short explanation will be helpful.

Sample component code

**App.js**

```
<><CustomInput /></>
```

**CustomInput.js**

```
function CustomInput(props) {
  console.log("This is rendering twice");
  const testRef = useRef(null);
  return <input type="text" />
}
```

Comment: is `App.js` rendering twice too? Do you check it?

Comment: Are you changing props? Also, you're not returning your `<input>` from that component. Can you start by fixing that and check if anything changes?

Comment: `useRef` does not cause a component to be rendered again. Likely the parent or any other code in that component that you didn't include causes the re-render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is not `useRef` but `<React.StrictMode>` in index.js file in your project.

The reason why this happens is an intentional feature of the `React.StrictMode`. It only happens in development mode and should help to find accidental side effects in the render phase.

Removing the wrapper `<React.StrictMode>` will solve the problem in development mode.

Comment: I don't have StrictMode set anywhere but still get this behavior?